# Set Gnome terminal's default charset to utf8

Tags: character-encoding, gnome-terminal

Currently, I opened my gnome terminal and the default charset is gb2312.

How can set the default charset to utf8 in Gnome terminal?

I checked the preference setting but seemed not to find it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer buried in an [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2078244) thread (I'd asked a similar question 
[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106421/gnome-terminal-unicode-chars-not-showing-locale-is-set-to-en-us-utf8/)):

`gconftool --set --type=string /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/encoding en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: +1 tried all other solutions suggested here but this one did the trick.

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: +1. This is the only solution that worked for me! All the other stackexchange answers to this question don't work.

Comment: If you come to this answer and you've "tried it all", this is your last stop. Only thing that worked for me in Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2):

Simply right-click anywhere on the terminal and select **Show Menubar** and from the menu bar you select **Terminal > Set Character Encoding > Unicode (UTF-8)**. At least this works using gnome-terminal 3.2.1.

Comment: But it won't keep the change next time you opened it.

Comment: Ok, but what's the output of `locale`? I think you need to set the systems locale to an UTF-8 variant e.g `en_US.UTF-8` in order to make it permanent. To list all enabled locales, run `locale -a`. To enable a locale, uncomment it in `/etc/locale.gen` and run `locale-gen` to update the list.

Comment: My locale is `en_US.UTF-8` but I'm still not getting UTF-8 encoding when I start `gnome-terminal`.